# Safari web extension ignores toolbar icon changes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I'm converting a working chrome manifest v3 extension to Safari.

Desired behaviour: use `chrome.action.setIcon` to change the icon in the toolbar according to characteristics of the viewed page.

Actual behaviour: works fine on Chrome. But Safari ignores the calls to `chrome.action.setIcon`. No exception is thrown by default (but see below).

In all cases, The parameter provided is of the form:

```
{
  path: {
    "16": "/assets/img/icon16.png",
    "19": "/assets/img/icon19.png",
    "32": "/assets/img/icon32.png",
    "38": "/assets/img/icon38.png",
    "48": "/assets/img/icon48.png",
    "64": "/assets/img/icon64.png",
    "128": "/assets/img/icon128.png"
   }
};
```

(I included sizes 19 and 38 because the Safari documentation says they should be provided.)

Since `chrome.action.setIcon` returns a promise, I then tried the following:

```
try
{
    chrome.action.setIcon( { /* object defined above */ }).then( 
        function() { console.log( "promise OK " ); }, 
        function() { console.log( "promise REJECTED " ); }
    );
}
catch( err )
{
    console.log("can't set icon" );
    console.log( err );
}
```

And this produces the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object". Whereas without the call to `then` no exception is thrown. Chrome continues to work as expected with the call to `then`.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: [action.setIcon() > Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/action/setIcon#browser_compatibility) - You're welcome in advance!